# Recover data on a bricked Nexus 5

Tags: data-recovery, unbricking, nexus-5

I bought a Nexus 5 just a few weeks ago and it died miserably yesterday without any apparent reason at all. I've read quite a few threads around the net about this and I haven't been able to power on the phone with the method suggested.

What I'd like to do now is trying to recover as much data as possible and/or wipe the phone completely [without losing warranty]. Is there a way to do so considering that:

- connecting the phone to the computer won't work
- I can't power on the phone in any way
- I can't reach the boot loader

What I've tried so far:

- holding the power button down for 10+ seconds
- holding the power and the volume (+ and -, either together or one by one) buttons for 10+ seconds
- did the steps above when disconnected from a/c, when connected to a/c and when connected to usb.
- phone recharged for a 10+ hours and did again all the steps above
- tried at different time of day with different stars configuration, swearing and being nice, swearing and being nice at the same time too.
- asked the help of all gods I'm aware of without any luck (does this suggest google is evil?)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't take it back to the shop? Or did you get it direct from Google?

Comment: Can you boot into recovery, and do a factory-reset from there? See [Google Help](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en&rd=1) for steps involved. This would wipe the phone, but not offer a backup (unless you have a custom recovery installed).

Comment: Do you have a wall A/C charger?  Leave the phone on the charger for a few hours, and then try powering it on with the charger still plugged in.  If it doesn't power on - nothing much you can do other than sending it in for in-warranty repair or replacement.

Comment: @MarkMayo I bought it from google. I can send it back but I'd like to recover some data that wasn't synced anywhere and also wipe my personal data.

Comment: @Izzy I cannot boot into recovery

Comment: @Chahk already tried but it didn't work

Comment: :( If it doesn't even power on, there's not much hope for data recovery. Send it in, and take it as a lesson to always take backups. (I learned that last year when 2 out of 4 disks in my RAID5 NAS died  simultaneously.)

Comment: it was a two weeks old phone with no much in it except all the progress I made with ankidroid studying kanji. that hurts. And it's also a little bit annoying I can't wipe my data before returning it back.

Comment: could you please mention what all steps have you already tried so far to get some useful suggestions?

Comment: @shub question updated with the informations you're looking for